# Nuget fails trying to fetch wrong package

Tags: c#, nuget

While build CI/CD pipiline on Github I am running Powershell script that pull and install various Nuget packages and then copy `\lib\net461\*` files to target folders. I run into very stange error (?) with Nuget that I don't even know on how to debug it:

Nuget trying to fetch package that is not defined and then fail on constrains. Here is the output:

```
PS C:\Projects> nuget.exe install CustomerSimulator -Version 1.0.7982.10992 -PreRelease -OutputDirectory C:\Temp\_125
Feeds used:
  C:\Users\jjasper22\.nuget\packages\
  https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\
  https://other/nuget/repository/1
  https://other/nuget/repository/2

Attempting to gather dependency information for package 'CustomerSimulator.1.0.7982.10992' with respect to project 'C:\Temp\_125', targeting 'Any,Version=v0.0'
Gathering dependency information took 30.16 sec
Attempting to resolve dependencies for package 'CustomerSimulator.1.0.7982.10992' with DependencyBehavior 'Lowest'
Unable to find a version of 'Remotion.Linq' that is compatible with 'NHibernate 5.3.10 constraint: Remotion.Linq (>= 2.2.0 && < 3.0.0)', 'Remotion.Linq.EagerFetching 2.2.0 constraint: Remotion.Linq (>= 2.2.0)'.
PS C:\Projects>
```

I checked 20 times that NHibernate version **5.2.0** define everywhere - I am **not using version 5.3.10 in any project**.

---> So where does this reference to NHibernate 5.3.10 come from ? <----

This is a little bit complicated dependency graph that each project could include a banch of  other projects.. so it is not trivial to traverse them all but I made it very sure that NHibernate lower version (5.2.0) is used **everywhere**.

P.S. Nuget version 5.11.0.10, `C:\Temp\_125` = empty temporary folder created to just a target for nuget `install` command

---

Strange fact 1: While running `nuget install` this way:

```
nuget.exe install CustomerSimulator -Version 1.0.7982.10992 -PreRelease -OutputDirectory C:\Temp\_125 -Framework net461
```

with `-Framework net461` parameter - does not complain on constrains but install/download only the `CustomerSimulator` project without any dependecies.

---

Strange fact 2: `-Framework net461` parameter could be set as `-Framework .NETFramework4.6.1` and it does work on my computer but does not work (unknown framework version) on Github Windows 2019 builder....

Comment: Is it possible that one of the packages in your graph declared NHibernate 5.3.10 once some time in the past?  NuGet considers packages immutable, so if the same packageid+version exists one different feeds with different contents (including dependencies), then your build will be non-deterministic (unless you start using Package Source Mapping added to VS 2022/.NET 6 SDK). If you have a devbox or CI agent that does not wipe the nuget folder between builds, if it has the "bad" package already installed, then it's going to show this behaviour as well.

Comment: @zivkan this is brilliant idea ! I am sure that this is an answer - could you post it as answer and I will add more details why this is an answer ?